# Python pandas: creating a discrete series from a cumulative

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame where there are several groups of numeric series where the values are cumulative. Consider the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Cat': ['A', 'A','A','A', 'B','B','B','B'], 'Indicator': [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4], 'Cumulative1': [1,3,6,7,2,4,6,9], 'Cumulative2': [1,3,4,6,1,5,7,12]})

In [74]:df
Out[74]: 
Cat  Cumulative1  Cumulative2  Indicator
0   A            1            1          1
1   A            3            3          2
2   A            6            4          3
3   A            7            6          4
4   B            2            1          1
5   B            4            5          2
6   B            6            7          3
7   B            9           12          4
```

I need to create discrete series for Cumulative1 and Cumulative2, with starting point being the earliest entry in 'Indicator'.

my Approach is to use diff()

```
In[82]: df['Discrete1'] = df.groupby('Cat')['Cumulative1'].diff()
Out[82]: df
  Cat  Cumulative1  Cumulative2  Indicator  Discrete1
0   A            1            1          1        NaN
1   A            3            3          2        2.0
2   A            6            4          3        3.0
3   A            7            6          4        1.0
4   B            2            1          1        NaN
5   B            4            5          2        2.0
6   B            6            7          3        2.0
7   B            9           12          4        3.0
```

I have 3 questions:

How do I avoid the NaN in an elegant/Pythonic way? The correct values are to be found in the original Cumulative series.

Secondly, how do I elegantly apply this computation to all series, say -

```
 cols = ['Cumulative1', 'Cumulative2']
```

Thirdly, I have a lot of data that needs this computation -- is this the most efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want to avoid NaNs, you want to fill them with the start values from the "cumulative" column:

```
df['Discrete1'] = df['Discrete1'].combine_first(df['Cumulative1'])
```

To apply the operation to all (or select) columns, broadcast it to all columns of interest:

```
sources = 'Cumulative1', 'Cumulative2'
targets = ["Discrete" + x[len('Cumulative'):] for x in sources]

df[targets] = df.groupby('Cat')[sources].diff()
```

You still have to condition the NaNs in a loop:

```
for s,t in zip(sources, targets):
    df[t] = df[t].combine_first(df[s])
```